# What is the difference between a missile and a “rocket”?

Tags: armed-conflict, palestine, rhetoric, 2023-israel-hamas-war

For some reason when people describe the projectiles launched by Palestinian forces into Israel, they refer to them as rockets. But in all other contexts it seems like such would be called missiles.

I would ask this on ELU but I have a feeling that the answer does not lie in the intrinsic semantic differences in the words (but perhaps it does), and instead for reasons of political sentiments and the like.

Comment: See, [What is the difference between a 'rocket' and a 'missile'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185955/346487) on ELU.

Comment: The difference between rocket and missile is not entirely clear but it's a distinction based on their design, not on political considerations. Qassams would also not be called missiles in another context.  A comparison may be to the Soviet Grad or the US MLRS, both of which are called *rocket* artillery. The fact that Hamas uses tactical battlefield weapons in a strategic role does not make them missiles.

Comment: I've not heard of either term to have some kind of political baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get why that's confusing. The two seem to describe the same thing.

- A **rocket** describes any sort of craft or projectile that is propelled by a combustion engine of some sort. This is most often driven by a chemical engine of some sort that is combusting fuel
- A **missile** is a rocket-based weapon that contains an explosive warhead and has some sort of guidance and control system (aiming the nozzle, turning fins on the body, etc.)

What confuses people is that the term "rocket" is really the superset (i.e. the whole group) and "missile" is a subset. Put a different way, all missiles are rockets, but not all rockets are missiles. SpaceX is a rocket company, even though their rockets have guidance and control. If you added a warhead to their [Falcon 9 rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9), it would become a missile.

#### The Israeli-Palestinian Weapon Terminology

Where this stops being an English lesson is when we talk about the weapons used in the conflict. The terms are usually used correctly, but because of the superset problem they can sometimes be used interchangeably (i.e. incorrectly). Let's break that down here.

The vast majority of weapons out there qualify as missiles. This includes weapons like

- Virtually all aircraft-launched rockets (especially the air-to-air variety)
- Ground-to-air weapons (i.e. anti-aircraft)
- Ground defense systems (like Israel's [Iron Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Dome) system, or the US-made anti-tank [Javelin missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FGM-148_Javelin))
- [Inter-Continental Ballistic Missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile) (ICBM, most often containing a nuclear payload)

Most of the groups that have been in conflict with Israel (most notably Hamas) have some version of the [Qassam rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qassam_rocket). These are low-tech ballistic projectiles with a much longer range than a mere mortar. What makes these a **rocket**, as opposed to a missile, is they contain no guidance system. Qassam rockets are meant to be cheap and easy to build. They fly until they have expended their fuel, then crash and usually explode their simple warheads in the process.

Comment: OTOH even Lockheed Martin isn't exactly consistent with such terms: says "HIMARS carries a six-pack of GMLRS rockets or one TACMS missile" on their own website. And the irony doesn't stop there; the 'R' in GMLRS stands for "rocket", and G for "guided", of course.

Comment: It looks like when they add [more] guidance to a system that was initially designed for less/unguided rockets, they keep the rocket term, as they also did with  Direct Attack Guided Rocket (DAGR).

Comment: not all missiles are rockets, some are jets, some use electric/compressed gas driven propellers (torpedoes), and some are passive, like a stone from a slingshot.

Comment: @dandavis: yeah, in British parlance in particular missile can even be qualified as "guided missile" https://www.britannica.com/technology/guided-missile apparently, because missile has a broader meaning. The same is in fact true in US parlance, in "guided missile destroyer" for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guided-missile_destroyer

Comment: Some missiles are not rockets. A rocket carries the oxidizer needed to combine with the fuel. Cruise missiles and scramjet missiles are indeed missiles, but they are air-breathers, so they are not rockets.